# react add search functionality alongside categories

Tags: reactjs

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import Spinner from './Spinner'

const Home = () => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState({
        category: 'All',
        searchBar: '',
    })

    const handleCategory = e => {
        setSearch({...search, category: e.target.id})
    }

    const handleSearch = e => {
        setSearch({...search, searchBar: e.target.value})
    }

    // This only works for the categories
    const filteredPreviews = search.category === 'All' 
    ? previews 
    : previews.filter(preview => preview.category === search.category)

    return (
        <div className="container">
            
            <section className="main-nav">
                <div className="main-nav-content">
                    <ul className='categories'>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='All'>All</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='Action'>Action</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='Adventure'>Adventure</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='Survival'>Survival</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='Simulation'>Simulation</a></li>
                        <li><a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id='Racing'>Racing</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul className='main-input'>
                        <li>
                            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
                            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)} placeholder="Search Games..." />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

        <section className="games">

        {
            filteredPreviews.map(preview => (
        
                <div>
                    <h3>{preview.title}</h3> 
                    <p>{preview.category}</p>
                </div>

            ))}
        </section>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Sample Data**

```
const previews = [
            {
              title: "Red Dead Redemption 2",
              category: "Survival",
            },
            {
              title: "FEAR",
              category: "Horror",
            },
            {
              title: "Battlefield 1",
              category: "Action",
            },
          ];
```

So I have a function that handles the current category that the user clicks on and displays the previews accordingly, but I cannot figure out how I let the user use the search input too, I tried using || conditionals and other things but in the end I couldnt figure it out, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const previews = [
  {
    title: "Red Dead Redemption 2",
    category: "Survival"
  },
  {
    title: "FEAR",
    category: "Horror"
  },
  {
    title: "Battlefield 1",
    category: "Action"
  }
];
const Home = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    category: "All",
    searchBar: ""
  });

  const handleCategory = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, category: e.target.id });
  };

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, searchBar: e.target.value,category :'' });
  };

  // This only works for the categories
  // Now this works for search too
  const filteredPreviews = () => {
    const { category, searchBar } = search;

    if (category === "All" || (searchBar && searchBar === "All")) {
      return previews;
    }

    const filtered = previews.filter((preview) => {
      if (
        preview.category === category ||
        (searchBar && searchBar === preview.category)
      ) {
        return preview;
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <section className="main-nav">
        <div className="main-nav-content">
          <ul className="categories">
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="All">
                All
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Action">
                Action
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Adventure">
                Adventure
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Survival">
                Survival
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Simulation">
                Simulation
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Racing">
                Racing
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul className="main-input">
            <li>
              <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}
                placeholder="Search Games..."
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="games">
        
        {filteredPreviews().map((preview) => (
          <div>
            <h3>{preview.title}</h3>
            <p>{preview.category}</p>
          </div>
        ))
        }
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const previews = [
  {
    title: "Red Dead Redemption 2",
    category: "Survival"
  },
  {
    title: "FEAR",
    category: "Horror"
  },
  {
    title: "Battlefield 1",
    category: "Action"
  }
];

const Home = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    category: "All",
    searchBar: ""
  });

  const handleCategory = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, category: e.target.id });
  };

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch({ ...search, searchBar: e.target.value });
  };

  // This only works for the categories
  // Now this works for search too
  const filteredPreviews = () => {
    const { category, searchBar } = search;

    if (category === "All" || (searchBar && searchBar === "All")) {
      return previews;
    }

    const filtered = previews.filter((preview) => {
      if (
        preview.category === category ||
        (searchBar && searchBar === preview.category)
      ) {
        return preview;
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <section className="main-nav">
        <div className="main-nav-content">
          <ul className="categories">
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="All">
                All
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Action">
                Action
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Adventure">
                Adventure
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Survival">
                Survival
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Simulation">
                Simulation
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a onClick={(e) => handleCategory(e)} id="Racing">
                Racing
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul className="main-input">
            <li>
              <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}
                placeholder="Search Games..."
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="games">
        {filteredPreviews().map((preview) => (
          <div>
            <h3>{preview.title}</h3>
            <p>{preview.category}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Luna, I have replied on this question earlier. The other person just copied my answer.